# ember tests failing using Mirage for GET requests

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I'm following [the tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.8.0/tutorial/ember-cli/) on the emberjs website. I have it all working but the tests are failing with 404s.

mirage/config.js

```
export default function() {
  this.namespace = '/api';
  this.get('/rentals', function(db, request){
    if(request.queryParams.city !== undefined) {
      let filteredRentals = rentals.filter(function(i){
        return i.attributes.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.queryParams.city.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
      });
      return { data: filteredRentals };
    } else {
      return { data: rentals };
    }
  });
}
```

application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

list-rentals-test.js

```
import { test } from 'qunit';
import moduleForAcceptance from 'super-rentals/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';

moduleForAcceptance('Acceptance | list rentals');

test('should redirect to rentals route.', function(assert) {
  visit('/');
  andThen(function(){
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/rentals', 'should redirect automatically');
  });
});
```

the result is

```
Not found: /api/rentals
should redirect automatically
Expected:   
  "/rentals"
Result:     
  "/"
```

The app works perfectly but I would like to get the tests to pass as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: As I know, you should initialize mirage for tests. Maybe these links will help: [http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/acceptance-testing/](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/acceptance-testing/) [http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/manually-starting-mirage/](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.2.x/manually-starting-mirage/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that restarting the test server fixed the issue.